# Why does Javascript Object dot notation cause an error?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, foreach

I've read a lot about the differences between dot notation and bracket notation in Javascript. My understanding is the following.

Dot notation:

- Property identifies can only be alphanumeric (and _ and $)
- Property identifiers cannot start with a number.
- Property identifiers cannot contain variables.
- OK — obj.prop_1, obj.prop$
- Not OK — obj.1prop, obj.prop name

Bracket notation:

- Property identifiers have to be a String or a variable that references a String.
- It is okay to use variables, spaces, and Strings that start with numbers
- OK — obj["1prop"], obj["prop name"]

So I still don't understand why my linter throws an error if I use dot notation, but not bracket notation in the following example.

```
    this.contactConfig = {
        "prop": "addresses",
        groups: [
            {
                "label": "Physical Address",
                "type": "address",
                "prop": 'physical_address',
                "controls": [
                    {
                        "label": "Address Line 1",
                        "prop": "address1"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Address Line 2",
                        "prop": "address2"

                    },
                    {
                        "label": "City",
                        "prop": "city"

                    },
                    {
                        "label": "State",
                        "prop": "state",
                        "type": "dropdown"

                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Zip Code",
                        "prop": "zipcode"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "Mailing Address",
                "type": "address",
                "prop": "mailling_address",
                "same": false,
                "controls": [
                    {
                        "label": "Address Line 1",
                        "prop": "mailing_address1"

                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Address Line 2",
                        "prop": "mailing_address2"

                    },
                    {
                        "label": "City",
                        "prop": "mailing_city"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "State",
                        "prop": "mailing_state",
                        "type": "dropdown"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Zip Code",
                        "prop": "mailing_zipcode"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "Contact",
                "prop": "contact",
                "controls": [
                    {
                        "label": "Email",
                        "prop": "email"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Primary Phone Number",
                        "prop": "primary_phone_number"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Secondary Phone Number",
                        "prop": "secondary_phone_number"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }

    this.profileForm = new FormGroup({});
    this.contactConfig["groups"].forEach(group => {
        console.log('group', group)
        group.controls.forEach(control => {
            this.formControlService.addFormGroupToFormGroup(this.profileForm, group);
        })
    })
```

My linter throws the following error if I use dot notation: `Property 'groups' does not exist on type '{}'.`

If I change my code to make `"groups"` `groups` I still get the same error. Any ideas why I have to use bracket notation?

TSLint error.
[image]

Comment: What "linter" are we talking about?

Comment: `this.contactConfig['groups]'` ... you mean `this.contactConfig['groups']` - is that the error? you've got a simple typo, the order of `]'` should be `']`

Comment: What type is `contactConfig` originally defined with? The error is likely because it has been created without having the property `groups` as part of the interface/class

Comment: It's defined as an object.  contactConfig = {}; If that's the case why don't I receive the error when I use bracket notation?

Answer (score 1):

You can use it with bracket notation. You just have a syntax error in it:

```
this.contactConfig['groups]'
```

should be:

```
this.contactConfig['groups']
```

```js
this.contactConfig = {
        prop: "addresses",
        groups: [
            {
                label: "Physical Address",
                type: "address",
                prop: 'physical_address',
                controls: [
                    {
                        label: "Address Line 1",
                        prop: "address1"
                    },
                    {
                        label: "Address Line 2",
                        prop: "address2"

                    },
                    {
                        label: "City",
                        prop: "city"

                    },
                    {
                        label: "State",
                        prop: "state",
                        type: "dropdown"

                    },
                    {
                        label: "Zip Code",
                        prop: "zipcode"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                label: "Mailing Address",
                type: "address",
                prop: "mailling_address",
                same: false,
                controls: [
                    {
                        label: "Address Line 1",
                        prop: "mailing_address1"

                    },
                    {
                        label: "Address Line 2",
                        prop: "mailing_address2"

                    },
                    {
                        label: "City",
                        prop: "mailing_city"
                    },
                    {
                        label: "State",
                        prop: "mailing_state",
                        type: "dropdown"
                    },
                    {
                        label: "Zip Code",
                        prop: "mailing_zipcode"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                label: "Contact",
                prop: "contact",
                controls: [
                    {
                        label: "Email",
                        prop: "email"
                    },
                    {
                        label: "Primary Phone Number",
                        prop: "primary_phone_number"
                    },
                    {
                        label: "Secondary Phone Number",
                        prop: "secondary_phone_number"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    };

    this.contactConfig['groups'].forEach(group => {
        console.log('group', group);
        group.controls.forEach(control => {
            this.formControlService.addFormGroupToFormGroup(this.profileForm, group);
        });
    });
```

And you can use dot notation as well:

```js
this.contactConfig = {
        prop: "addresses",
        groups: [
            {
                label: "Physical Address",
                type: "address",
                prop: 'physical_address',
                controls: [
                    {
                        label: "Address Line 1",
                        prop: "address1"
                    },
                    {
                        label: "Address Line 2",
                        prop: "address2"

                    },
                    {
                        label: "City",
                        prop: "city"

                    },
                    {
                        label: "State",
                        prop: "state",
                        type: "dropdown"

                    },
                    {
                        label: "Zip Code",
                        prop: "zipcode"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                label: "Mailing Address",
                type: "address",
                prop: "mailling_address",
                same: false,
                controls: [
                    {
                        label: "Address Line 1",
                        prop: "mailing_address1"

                    },
                    {
                        label: "Address Line 2",
                        prop: "mailing_address2"

                    },
                    {
                        label: "City",
                        prop: "mailing_city"
                    },
                    {
                        label: "State",
                        prop: "mailing_state",
                        type: "dropdown"
                    },
                    {
                        label: "Zip Code",
                        prop: "mailing_zipcode"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                label: "Contact",
                prop: "contact",
                controls: [
                    {
                        label: "Email",
                        prop: "email"
                    },
                    {
                        label: "Primary Phone Number",
                        prop: "primary_phone_number"
                    },
                    {
                        label: "Secondary Phone Number",
                        prop: "secondary_phone_number"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    };

    this.contactConfig.groups.forEach(group => {
        console.log('group', group);
        group.controls.forEach(control => {
            this.formControlService.addFormGroupToFormGroup(this.profileForm, group);
        });
    });
```

Additionally (FYI), with object literals, your object keys/property names do not need to be quoted unless you are trying to create a JSON string. Lastly, it's a really good idea not to rely on the automatic semicolon insertion and instead, put semicolons in yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the syntax corrections. I accidentally put the quote in the wrong place when I was formatting for StackOverFlow, but in my code it's correct. My linter is giving me an error when I use dot notation.

Comment: Is it possible that in Typescript it's stricter?

Comment: @London804 Not about this it's not, both forms of syntax are perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your problem is with the syntax of the data object, but with how you are trying to retrieve it.

Just tried this with your object and it works fine:

```
this.contactConfig.groups.forEach(group => {
    console.log(group);
});
```

Comment: I don't know what to say other then I'm getting the error above. I don't think it's a Typescript thing.